# how to upload files with ajax jquery in symfony3

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, symfony, file-upload

hey everybody i have problem with uploading file with ajax in symfony3 i detect event of selecting file without submit or click with ajax, jquery, but i have nothing to get in method controller the request is always null

the first console.log(file_data) return

```
File {name: "pawandeep.jpg", lastModified: 1489747066000, lastModifiedDate: Fri Mar 17 2017 11:37:46 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 30970…}
```

the last console.log(data) return null !!!

```
<form method="post" action="#" id = "myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <div id="mybutton">
        <input type="file" id="myfile" name="upload"/>
            Click Me!
    </div>
</form>
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%">
    </div>
</div>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.progress').hide();
        $('#myfile').change(function(evt) {

            /*srcPhoto = $(this).val();*/
            $('.progress').show();
            var file_data = $("#myfile").prop("files")[0];
            console.log(file_data);
            var form_data = new FormData(file_data);                  // Creating object of FormData class
            /*form_data.append("file", file_data)*/
            /*form_data.append("id", "{{ doctor.id }}")*/
            if(file_data != ""){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{{ path('bonjou', {'id':doctor.id}) }}", // Url to which the request is send
                    type: "POST", // Type of request to be send, called as method
                    data: form_data, // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
                    contentType: false, // The content type used when sending data to the server.
                    cache: false, // To unable request pages to be cached
                    processData: false, // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
                    mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
                    dataType:"json",
                    success: function (data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
                    {
                        $(".progress").hide();
                        console.log(data);
                        $(".photoDoctor").attr("src", data.name);
                    }
            });
            };
        });
    });
</script>
```

**File rooting**

```
bonjou:
    path:    /akrem/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: DoctorsAdminBundle:Doctor:akrem }
```

**method controller**

```
 public function akremAction(Request $request, $id)
 {
     $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
     $doctor = $em->getRepository('DoctorsAdminBundle:Doctor')->find($id);
     $file = $request->files->get('upload');
     $countryArray = array(
        'file'=>$file
     );
     return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse($countryArray);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your script to

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.progress').hide();
    $('#myfile').change(function(evt) {

        /*srcPhoto = $(this).val();*/
        $('.progress').show();
        var file_data = $("form")[0];
        console.log(file_data);
        var form_data = new FormData(file_data);                  // Creating object of FormData class
        /*form_data.append("file", file_data)*/
        /*form_data.append("id", "{{ doctor.id }}")*/
        if(file_data != ""){
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ path('bonjou', {'id':doctor.id}) }}", // Url to which the request is send
                type: "POST", // Type of request to be send, called as method
                data: form_data, // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
                contentType: false, // The content type used when sending data to the server.
                cache: false, // To unable request pages to be cached
                processData: false, // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
                mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
                dataType:"json",
                success: function (data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
                {
                    $(".progress").hide();
                    console.log(data);
                    $(".photoDoctor").attr("src", data.name);
                }
        });
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: no the first  console.log(file_data) return undefined !!

Comment: you are trying to pass the file individualy nstead try to pass the whole form it will get you result

Comment: ill post an example

Comment: the same result file undefined !

Answer (score 0):

```
function SubmitForm() {
        var data = $("#policyForm").serialize();
        var url = "/Policies/NewPolicy"
        var form = $('#policyForm')[0]
        var formdata = false;
        if (window.FormData) {
            formdata = new FormData(form);
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: formdata ? formdata : data,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {//Your successcode}
```

Comment: i get this result {"files":[]}

Answer (score 0):

if you want go to my company blog, he has topic in upload files with ajax jquery in symfony3

http://blog.eleven-labs.com/en/upload-file-ajax/

Answer (score 0):

i want to give you the answer and it works fine for me enjoy !

twig view

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                        {#<button type="button" id="mybutton" class="updatePhotoDoctor btn btn-default arabe">تعديل</button>#}
                                        {{ form_start(editPicForm, {"attr":{"id":"akrem"}}) }}
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            {#Génération du label. #}
                                            {{ form_label(editPicForm.photoDoctor, "صورة الطبيب", {'label_attr': {'class': 'arabe control-label'}}) }}

                                            {#Affichage des erreurs pour ce champ précis.#}
                                            {{ form_errors(editPicForm.photoDoctor) }}
                                            {#Génération de l'input.#}
                                            {{ form_widget(editPicForm.photoDoctor, {'attr': {'class': 'arabe'}}) }}
                                        </div>
                                        {#<div class="form-group">
                                             Génération du label.
                                            {{ form_label(editPicForm.password, "كلمة المرور", {'label_attr': {'class': 'arabe control-label'}}) }}

                                             Affichage des erreurs pour ce champ précis.
                                            {{ form_errors(editPicForm.passwordDoctor) }}
                                             Génération de l'input.
                                            {{ form_widget(editPicForm.passwordDoctor, {'attr': {'class': 'arabe'}}) }}
                                        </div>#}
                                        <div class="progress">
                                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated"
                                                 role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0"
                                                 aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <input type="submit" value="تعديل"/>
                                        {{ form_end(editPicForm) }}

                                    </div>
```

script ajax

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.progress').hide();
        $('#akrem').on("submit", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('.progress').show();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "{{ path('doctors_admin_editPhotoDoctor', {'id':doctor.id}) }}",
                data: new FormData($(this)[0]),
                dataType: 'json',
                processData: false,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response.photo);
                    $('#doctorPic').attr('src', '{{ asset('uploads/doctors/') }}' + response.photo);
                    $('.doctorPic').attr('src', '{{ asset('uploads/doctors/') }}' + response.photo);
                    /*alert(response.message);
                     console.log(response);*/
                    $('.progress').hide();
                },
                error: function (response, desc, err) {
                    if (response.responseJSON && response.responseJSON.message) {
                        alert(response.responseJSON.message);
                    }
                    else {
                        alert(desc);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Routing

```
doctors_admin_editPhotoDoctor:
    path:     /editPhotoDoctor/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: DoctorsAdminBundle:Doctor:editPhotoDoctor }
    requirements:
        id: \d
```

Controller

```
public function editPhotoDoctorAction(Request $request, Doctor $doctor)
{

    $editPictureForm = $this->createForm('Doctors\AdminBundle\Form\EditPictureDoctorType', $doctor);
    $editForm = $this->createForm('Doctors\AdminBundle\Form\EditDoctorType', $doctor);
    $editPictureForm->handleRequest($request);
    if ($editPictureForm->isSubmitted()) {
        $file = $doctor->getPhotoDoctor();
        $doctor->setPhotoDoctor($file); // Store the current value from the DB before overwriting below
        /*if ($file instanceof UploadedFile) {*/
        $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();
        $file->move(
            $this->getParameter('photoDoctor_directory'),
            $fileName
        );
        $doctor->setPhotoDoctor($fileName);
        /*}*/
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {

            return new JsonResponse(array('message' => 'Success!','success' => true, 'photo'=>$doctor->getPhotoDoctor()), 200);

        }
        $session = $request->getSession();
        $session->getFlashBag()->add('msg', 'تم تعديل معلومات الطبيب  بنجاح');
        return $this->redirectToRoute('doctors_admin_doctors');
    }
    /*var_dump($editForm->getErrors());*/
    return $this->render('DoctorsAdminBundle:Doctor:editDoctor.html.twig', array(
        'doctor' =>$doctor,
        'edit_form' =>$editForm->createView(),
        'editPicForm'=>$editPictureForm->createView(),
    ));

}
```